# How to iterate through Ruby/Rails relation

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, object, iteration

I have a model, FacebookProfile, that has three columns, a, b and c.

I invoke this object by doing:

```
@facebook_profile = FacebookProfile.find_by_facebook_id(1)
```

Then I can access each of the values for the columns a, b and c

```
@facebook_profile.a # result: 1
@facebook_profile.b # result: 2
@facebook_profile.c # result: 3
```

If I have an array of items a, b and c, how can I iterate through calling these on @facebook_profile?

My best guess:

```
my_array = ["a", "b", "c"]
for i in my_array
  puts @facebook_profile.i
end
```

Expected output: 1, 2, 3

I have seen a way to iterate through all columns, but I have other columns besides a, b and c, so I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the `send`operator to do something along the lines of

```
my_array = ["a","b","c"]

for i in my_array
  puts @facebook_profile.send(i.to_sym)
end
```

Comment: I'm getting "unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end" when I implement this like this => @facebook_profile.send(s.to_sym) = new_tags. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Oh, stumbled upon a fix: @facebook_profile.send(s + '=', new_tags) It's a bit awkward, but it'll do. Thanks!